# Veeam and Hyper-V - Failed to flush change tracking data. Using full scan incremental run

Tags: backup, veeam

Windows Server 2012 R2 - Hyper-V.
I have tried already:

1. reset CBT by using Reset-HvVmChangeTracking command
2. disabled host CBT than run  sc stop VeeamFCT than removed registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\VeeamFCT\Parameters\CTDB", enabled CBT on host again and rerun jobs
3. remove host from veeam and add again

Unfortunatelly nothing helped. Any ideas ?